# Como sortear números de uma lista, de forma aleatória e sem repetições?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, random

Como faço para sortear 9 números em uma lista de 15, sem repetir os números sorteados?
Utilizo o Python 3.8.

```
import random
for c in range (1, 16):
    n1 = str(input("Digite um nº: "))
l = [n1]
random.shuffle(l)
print("NÚMEROS ESCOLHIDOS: ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
```

Comment: Partilha o que já tentaste.

Comment: import random
for c in range (1, 16):
    n1 = str(input("Digite um nº: "))
l = [n1]
random.shuffle(l)
print("NÚMEROS ESCOLHIDOS: ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)
print(" ", l)

Comment: já tentei com um parecido, porém nao foi tbm

Comment: Edita a tua questão e coloca lá o teu código

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta usar [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), que já garante que não haverá repetição.

Mas antes um detalhe. Você está pedindo que o usuário digite 15 números, então você precisa guardar todos eles na lista (da forma que você fez, somente o último é colocado nela). E se vai usar o `range` somente para executar algo várias vezes (e tanto faz o valor usado na iteração), basta fazer apenas `range(15)`.

E [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input(...))` é redundante e desnecessário. Se quer garantir que foi digitado um número, você pode usar [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) para converter a string para número (e capturar o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) caso não seja digitado um número).

Então ficaria assim:

```
from random import sample

numeros = []
for _ in range(15):
    while True:
        try:
            numeros.append(int(input("Digite um nº: ")))
            break # interrompe o while e vai para a próxima iteração do for
        except ValueError:
            print('não foi digitado um número')

print("NÚMEROS ESCOLHIDOS: ", sample(numeros, 9))
```

No `for` eu uso `_`, que é uma convenção do Python para indicar que a variável não é usada no *loop* (pois só me interessa executar algo 15 vezes).

Depois, o `while` executa enquanto não for digitado um número (pois aí cai no bloco `except`). Se for digitado um número, este é adicionado na lista, o `break` interrompe o `while` e ele vai para a próxima iteração do `for`.

Por fim, tendo a lista com os 15 números, eu uso `random.sample` para obter os 9 números, sem repetição.

Comment: MUITOOOS OBRIGADA!!! rodou agora só eu conseguir fazer que apareça 50 opções com o numero misturados, muitoo obrigada! Eu não sabia dessas dicas ai que você deu, obrigada mesmo

Comment: eeey onde você aprendeu essas coisas?

Comment: @Aragon Se está falando do funcionamento do site, foi na [help]. Se está falando de Python, eu sempre consulto a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html) - e para dúvidas específicas, o próprio Stack Overflow tem bastante material :-)

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
from random import sample


def sorteio_sem_repeticoes():
    return sorted(sample(range(1, 16), 9))


print(sorteio_sem_repeticoes())
```

Observe que os valores neste código já estão pré-fixados, ou seja, este código  criará uma lista com `9` elementos sorteados de dentro do intervalo fechado **[1, 15]**.

Agora se você deseja realizar um sorteio com um número de sorteados variados e com range diferente, você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
from random import sample


def sorteio_sem_repeticoes(n, i, f):
    return sorted(sample(range(i, f + 1), n))


num = int(input('Desejas sortear quantos números? '))
ini = int(input('Digite o limite inicial do range: '))
fin = int(input('Digite o limite final do range: '))

print(sorteio_sem_repeticoes(num, ini, fin))
```

Neste código devemos informar a quantidade de valores a ser sorteados e os limites inferior e superior do range. Importante observar que com este último código podemos sortear `n` valores de um range cujo `i` corresponde ao limite inferior do range e `f` corresponde ao limite superior.

Comment: Entendi, obrigada, está funcionando muitoo bem, obrigada!!!